# No suitable driver found for Hibernate using Jersey

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey

I am doing a program of hibernate with Jersey using `mysql.all` configuration is correct as I had run the program through main.and got the desired output. but when I call the program as web application and hit the rest URL it gives connection

> org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
>     at com.util.EmpUtil.selecthql(EmpUtil.java:76)  at
>   com.util.RestController.selectAll(RestController.java:47)
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)

I am getting session object and i have all jars attached.as program is running using main function.Is there any difference between running a program using main and as web application.

Comment: have you added mysql jar in your path?

Comment: yes i have added  mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar ,that's why I am getting output when running program using main....

Comment: may be you need to post your code then? then only we can sortout